# XSLT: How do I match on the first occurrence of a given element?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:template match="//foo[1]">
```

matches multiple elements (every `<foo>` that has no previous `<foo>` siblings)

```
<xsl:template match="(//foo)[1]">
```

is an error.

How do I match on just the first occurrence of an element in the document?

Here's an example of the input document:

```
<test>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <another>
        <foo>2</foo>
    </another>
    <more>
        <bar>3</bar>
        <foo>4</foo>
    </more>
    <something>
        <foo>5</foo>
        <bar>6</bar>
        <foo>7</foo>
    </something>
    <final>
        <hum>8</hum>
        <foo>9</foo>
        <foo>10</foo>
    </final>
</test>
```

My intention is to match the `foo` with text `1` and *no others*. Assume `foo` can occur *anywhere* in the document.

Comment: Hmm, <xsl:template match="(//foo)[1]"> looks good to me, what XSTL processor are you using ?

Comment: @zeppelin Which processor are *you* using?

Comment: @zeppelin I'm using libxslt 1.1.28 via PHP, and libxslt 10128 via xsltproc on the command line

Comment: Ah, I see you are trying to apply it in with the  "match"  attribute, which only supports a subset of XPath (patterns), which is why you get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match only the first occurrence of `foo` in the document, you have to check both that there are no preceding `foo` elements and that there are no `foo` ancestors:

```
<xsl:template match="foo[not(preceding::foo or ancestor::foo)]">
```

**Consider the following sample input XML:**

```
<r>
  <a/>
  <foo>
    <b/>
    <foo/>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <foo/>
  </foo>
  <c/>
</r>
```

**This XSLT,**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo[not(preceding::foo or ancestor::foo)]">
    <FirstFoo>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </FirstFoo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <LaterFoo>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </LaterFoo>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**will output this XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
  <a/>
  <FirstFoo>
      <b/>
      <LaterFoo/>
  </FirstFoo>
  <LaterFoo>
      <LaterFoo/>
  </LaterFoo>
  <c/>
</r>
```

**but if you only check the preceding axis, you'll output this XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
  <a/>
  <FirstFoo>
      <b/>
      <FirstFoo/>
  </FirstFoo>
  <LaterFoo>
      <LaterFoo/>
  </LaterFoo>
  <c/>
</r>
```

Comment: As it happens, my document should never include a `foo` within a `foo`, but I thought `preceding` matched ancestors anyway?

Comment: @BobbyJack: No, checking preceding won't cover ancestors.  I've updated the answer to show a specific example.

Comment: Good and precise! +1. It is good to make incorrect answers disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved with a key where you then identify the first item in the group of `foo` elements, using XSLT 2.0 this looks like

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="foo-group" match="foo" use="node-name(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo[. is key('foo-group', node-name(.))[1]]">
        <foo id="first-foo">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </foo>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:transform>
```

online at http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLb.

Using XSLT 1.0 you can use the `local-name` or `name` (or if needed namespace and name) to achieve the same, only as the `is` operator does not exist you need to use `generate-id` to identify the first item:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="foo-group" match="foo" use="local-name()"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo[generate-id() = generate-id(key('foo-group', local-name())[1])]">
        <foo id="first-foo">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </foo>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/ejivdH9.

Finally using XSLT 3.0 we can write this as

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="foo-group" match="foo" use="node-name(.)"/>

  <xsl:param name="foo-name" as="xs:QName" select="xs:QName('foo')"/>

  <xsl:template match="key('foo-group', $foo-name)[1]">
    <foo id="first-foo">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It would be nicer not to need the `<xsl:param name="foo-name" as="xs:QName" select="xs:QName('foo')"/>` and to use `<xsl:template match="key('foo-group', xs:QName('foo'))[1]">` instead but even the more powerful XSLT 3.0 match patterns only allow us to use a function like `key` if the arguments are literals or variables/parameters.